# media print не меняет длину body

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

Всем привет , столкнулся с такой проблемой когда адаптировал сайт для печати(print)
есть блок , `background1` это этакий body для половины сайта , их там 2.
При попытке сменить height в media print (у меня отдельный print.css файл)
Совершенно ничего не происходит , не длина не меняется , ничего.
Есть ли догадки как можно решить проблему?
Спасибо
вот код.

```
.background1 {
    background:url(sahara.jpg) no-repeat; 
display:block;
width:100%;
height:675px;
margin:0 auto;

float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, Решил проблему сам, присвоил !important к background1 который находился в файле print.css , и все заработало.
вот код кому понадобится

```
.background1 {
    background:url(sahara.jpg) no-repeat; 
display:block;
width:100%;
height:675px !important;
margin:0 auto;

float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Ну использование !important нежелательно, но если дальнейшая правка не нужна, то вариант вполне рабочий.

Comment: Почему не желательно? так ведь , он только для print версии , а сидеть и пролистывать весь код изза которого в файле print.css не меняется .background1  , дело не самое быстрое как я знаю.